# Как склеить несколько input по боковым границам

Tags: html, input

Есть форма, в которой в одну строку идёт несколько `input`, причём боковые границы у них общие. Как это реализовать?
Нужно также учитывать, что над каждым `input` есть соответствующий ему `label`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно вот так например(https://jsfiddle.net/Vladimir_Yamshik/nc3foLkb/1/`border-right: 0;border-left: 0;`)